# why we use session() method in laravel while working with session?

Tags: laravel, session

** I am working with the session. I read the documentation about the session from laravel website but I don't understand it well. why we use the session() method in the below code?

```
$request->session()->put(['key' => 'value']);
```

we are using the request object from the HTTP request after that what does the session() method does??

Comment: Everything about the session can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session, including accessing it from the `$request` variable: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#retrieving-data and globally via the `session()` helper: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#the-global-session-helper. "There is little practical difference between using the session via an HTTP request instance versus using the global session helper." Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I just want to know what the session() method does? is it use to start the session?

Comment: `session()` is used to access the session... it doesn't do anything per-se, but returns an instance of `SessionManager` (https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.html) that lets you chain methods, like `put()`, `has()`, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is same as session()->put you just writing some data to session, so for example use it later some where. Session data is stored in the server, and accessed by special session cookie.

Comment: my question is about what session() method does? does it mean we start the session then put some data into the session variable?